# Словил ошибку: Error: queryA EREFUSED smtp.gmail.com при попытке отправить сообщение из nodemailer. Кто знает как починить?

Tags: node.js, express, smtp, node-modules

**Собственно говоря её величество ошибка**

```
2022-04-22T19:41:36: Error: queryA EREFUSED smtp.gmail.com

2022-04-22T19:41:36: at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:dns:213:19) {

2022-04-22T19:41:36: errno: undefined,

2022-04-22T19:41:36: code: 'EDNS',

2022-04-22T19:41:36: syscall: 'queryA',

2022-04-22T19:41:36: hostname: 'smtp.gmail.com',

2022-04-22T19:41:36: command: 'CONN'

2022-04-22T19:41:36: }
```

**А вот и код создания подключения**

```
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer'

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // upgrade later with STARTTLS
    auth: {
        user: "Тут типо почта",
        pass: "тут как бы пароль",
    },
    rejectUnauthorized: false
});
```

Кто знает как пофиксить? Уже перепробовал все что только можно. Использую express и nodemailer. Пробовал как через smtp так и через gmail.

**Ошибка при smtp**

```
2022-04-22T14:08:41: Error: queryA EREFUSED s211.netx.hosting

2022-04-22T14:08:41: at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:dns:213:19) {

2022-04-22T14:08:41: errno: undefined,

2022-04-22T14:08:41: code: 'EDNS',

2022-04-22T14:08:41: syscall: 'queryA',

2022-04-22T14:08:41: hostname: 's211.netx.hosting',

2022-04-22T14:08:41: command: 'CONN'

2022-04-22T14:08:41: }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Проверьте какой пароль используется для почты. С 30 мая для gmail нужно получать специальный код через аккаунт в гугле.
2. Попробуйте подключиться к интернету через мобильный интернет. Возможно проблема на стороне провайдера.